# Changing an element in an Array in C#

Tags: c#

What is the difference between these two lines of codes?

1. `arrayOneF[i + 1].Replace(arrayOneF[i + 1], "x");`
2. `arrayOneF[i + 1] = arrayOneF[i + 1].Replace(arrayOneF[i + 1], "x");`

The code in number two gives the needed result whereas, in number one, the line is executed but doesn't give what I want. Why do I have to make the element[i+1] equal to the code? Isn' the code in number one enough to make changes to the element?

Comment: 1 calls a method on an object in the array. 2 replaces the object in the array with the return value from that method call. Is the object of the question to get us to guess what you're trying to do here? Were you once bitten by a page of documentation, and now you're afraid to read documentation yourself? I sympathize, but the only thing to do is get back on that pony, cowboy!

Comment: Try this: `string a = "food"; a.Replace("o", "e"); Console.WriteLine(a);`.  The console will write `food`.  On the other hand, `string a = "food"; string b = a.Replace("o", "e"); ConsoleWriteLine(b);` will write `feed`.

Answer (score 3):

Replace returns a new instance of whatever data.  It does not replace the value in the source data.  That's why with first example, replacement is done and returned as new value. Since it is not assigned to anything, it is lost.

In the second case, you actually assign the value back to the same array position, capturing the result of replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in C# are immutable.  `Replace` returns a new string; it does not modify the original string in any way.  So in the first example you're making a new string and immediately discarding it.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The misunderstanding here is in the nature of the Replace method; it has nothing to do with arrays.  Edit: well, the other answers are correct, too, but this is the clearest statement of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first line calls the `Replace` method on whatever object is stored in `arrayOneF[i + 1]` with the supplied parameters - from the code it appears to be a string.

As a string, the result will be returned and discarded, as it isn't used. The original string is not changed, since stings in c# are immutable.

The second line does the same, only the retun value gets assigned to the same slot in the array.